# php javascript redirection issue

Tags: javascript, php, redirect

i have 2 php pages  page1.php and page2.php

page1.php redirects to page2.php with an id paramater

page2.php?id=8923423672222

page1.php code

```
<?
 $id = "4556745767";
 echo "<script language=\"javascript\">function gopage2(){top.window.location.href=\"http://www.example.com/page2.php?id=".$id."\";}setTimeout('gopage2()',1000);</script>";
?>
```

page2.php code

```
<?
$id = $_GET['id'];
if($id!='')
{
 section = "section1";
}
else
{
 section = "section2";
}
echo "<script language=\"javascript\">function gosite(){top.window.location.href=\"http://www.example.com/".$section."/\";}setTimeout('gosite()',1000);</script>";
?>
```

in some cases page1.php doesn't redirect to page2.php
the reason of using javascript here that i want to be sure the user has javascript enabled, but in my tracking systems its report that page1 not redirecting in about 40% of requests and this is not reasonable , most of request comes from real hits

any help if there is any syntax or semantic wrong here

Comment: ummm ... `top.window...` ??? how about just `window...`

Comment: i need it to prevent embedding the page inside frames